How to create a layout similar to Walkthrough screen in Android?
I am implementing a feature in my android app. This feature has multiple parts. One of the part requires user to complete a 5 step process in order for successful completion.
Currently I have implemented this using a full screen dialog fragment, which contains a view pager that shows 5 different fragments.
Dialog Fragment Class implementation:
class Walkthrough(
context: Context,
private val cfm: FragmentManager,
private val cycleLife: Lifecycle,
val viewModel: EnrollDeviceViewModel,
val managementViewModel: ManagementViewModel,
val lambdaClient: LambdaClient) : DialogFragment(), OnClickListener, ViewPagerControl {

private lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager2
private lateinit var button: Button
private lateinit var prev: Button
private lateinit var cancel: ImageView
var TAG = "Enrollment"
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.walkthrough, container, false)
    Log.d(
        TAG,
        "Walkthrough: onCreateView() called with: inflater = $inflater, container = $container, savedInstanceState = $savedInstanceState"
    )
    viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.walkthrough_pager)
    viewPager.isUserInputEnabled = false
    viewPager.offscreenPageLimit = 5

    button = view.findViewById(R.id.walkthrough_next)
    prev = view.findViewById(R.id.walkthrough_prev)
    cancel = view.findViewById(R.id.cancelDialog)

    return view
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    Log.d(
        TAG,
        "onViewCreated() called"
    )

    val one = FragOne.getInstance(viewModel, managementViewModel, lambdaClient)
    val two = FragmentTwo(viewModel, lambdaClient)
    val three = FragmentThree()
    val four = FragmentFour(viewModel)
    val five = FragmentFive()

    val fragments2 = arrayListOf(
        one,
        two,
        three,
        four,
        five
    )

    val adapter = WalkthroughAdapter(cfm, fragments2, cycleLife)

    viewPager.adapter = adapter

    button.setOnClickListener {
        goToNextPage()
    }

    prev.setOnClickListener {
        goToPrevPage()
    }

    cancel.setOnClickListener {
        Log.d(TAG, "Walkthrough: cancel button clicked")
        viewModel.resetViewModelState()
        dismiss()
    }

}

override fun onClick(view: View?) {

}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    Log.d(TAG, "Walkthrough: onResume() called")
    val viewGrp = dialog?.window?.attributes
    viewGrp?.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    viewGrp?.height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT

    dialog?.window?.attributes = viewGrp
}

override fun goToNextPage() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Walkthrough: goToNextPage() called")

    when (viewPager.currentItem) {
        0 -> {
            viewPager.currentItem = 1
            prev.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

        1 -> viewPager.currentItem = 2

        2 -> {
            viewPager.currentItem = 3
            button.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }
}

override fun goToPrevPage() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Walkthrough: goToPrevPage() called")
    when (viewPager.currentItem) {
        1 -> {
            viewPager.currentItem = 0
            prev.visibility = View.GONE
        }

        2 -> viewPager.currentItem = 1
        3 -> {
            viewPager.currentItem = 2
            button.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }
}

}
Walkthrough Class (Dialog Fragment class) Layout file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/black"
>


<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/walkthrough_pager"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:scrollIndicators="bottom"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/walkthrough_next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Next"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/walkthrough_prev"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Prev"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cancelDialog"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icsharpcancel"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    /></androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

There is a close button at the top of this layout which close the dialog using dismiss() method .
Fragment State Adapter implementation:
class WalkthroughAdapter(
fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
private val fragments: List<Fragment>,
lifecycle: Lifecycle): FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle
) {


override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return fragments.size
}



override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
    return fragments[position]
}}

Now the problem is, when the app runs for the first time, and this dialog fragment is opened, everything works fine. But when the fragment is opened for second time and more, a new fragment object is created along with the old object. And so because of this, the code in the fragment class executes two times. And this is happening for any number of time, I am opening and closing the dialog fragment. I tried destroying the fragments on the click of close button in Walkthrough.class but IllegalStateException occurs with error message Fragment already added
What to do?
Is there any better way of implementing this or any way to fix this issue.
This is the part where I initialize and show Walkthrough dialog.
    override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    userAlertClient = UserAlertClient(activity)
    lambdaClient = LambdaClient(activity?.applicationContext)
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(ManagementViewModel::class.java)
    enrollDeviceViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(EnrollDeviceViewModel::class.java)

    binding.enrollDevice.setOnClickListener {

        val ctx = context
        if(ctx != null ) {
            val walkthrough = Walkthrough(
                ctx,
                childFragmentManager,
                lifecycle,
                enrollDeviceViewModel,
                viewModel,
                lambdaClient
            )
            walkthrough.show(childFragmentManager, "enroll")
            walkthrough.isCancelable = false
        }

    }
    setAdapter(deviceList)
    getDeviceList()

}


how about keep a Boolean variable that maintain if dialog already open or not, keep it's value in shared preference to make sure that it does not open again even if app restarts

This will not help with Fragment objects. Suppose I opened  and closed the dialog 10 times. Now when I open the dialog 11th time, the previous 10 objects are not destroyed and now the 11th object has been created. so the code in the fragment will execute 11 times. This is happening in the code. When the dialog is being dismissed, the the fragment objects are not getting destroyed.

please write code where you intialize Walkthrough dialog and open it
